# キャッシュした画像が表示されない

Tags: django, nginx

ElasticBeanstalkでDjangoのWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
画像の読み込みが遅いので、クライアントのブラウザで画像をキャッシュさせて表示させたいと考えています。

そこで、nginxのパラメータを変更し、試したところ、画像が表示されない現象が起こりました。

.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/proxy.confを以下の内容で作成しただけです。

```
 location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
     if ($upstream_status = "200") {
         expires 30d;
         add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
     }
 }
```

ALBを用いてHTTPSでの通信を行っています。

何が原因かさっぱり分からないので、少しでも情報が頂けると幸いです。

Comment: クライアントがその画像にアクセスした際に、どのようなレスポンスが返っていますか？
（これはブラウザの開発者ツールや、`curl` コマンドの使用などで観察できます）
その際、サーバー側のログには何が出ていますか